# How to create a AVD to fit on my monitor size?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I would like to create a device in AVD manager of android studio based on my monitor size and resolution. I tried to put the size and resolution of device based on my monitor but I don't get actual result.

My goal is when I run the AVD it fits completely to my monitor.
For example my monitor size is 14" and the resolution is 1366 x 768.
I want when run the AVD it fits on my screen and I just be able to see the android home screen.

[image]

[image]

[image: it's what I got with my configuration]
[image: it's what I want to have]

Comment: Have you tried removing device frame?  What is the outcome when you are setting it to your screens resolution? Do you have a screenshot you can share.

Comment: @TomD I edit my post. you can see that in 14" monitor my AVD fill only a portion of the space. I need it to fill whole space.

Comment: Nobody knows what should I do? :(

Comment: Is covering >95% of your screen ok?  I have managed to get it to cover almost the whole screen.  What is the purpose of coving the whole screen?

Comment: No it is only covers the center. You can see it in the picture.I want to use my monitor completely as android display. I want the emulator stretch to the monitor size.

Comment: @TomD I edited my question. maybe the new pics explain my problem better.

Answer (score 1):

AVD already has it own default screen size!

> since you want to make it work on full screen
>   So, I would suggest some of the following ways:-
>   *choose Either way*

1. **Use The android TV option while setting your project device**
2. **Dig deep into Android Studio settings in AVD flag to Customise**

*Any of this would work but remember to check out your active.xml file too to fill the screen by your app*